# Excel formula to show differences in columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

In Excel, I want to highlight the difference between 2 columns so that I can see if the person's money has increased or decreased by more than £500 since last month.

I don't want to add a 3rd column to show this so wanted it to be a case of if the figure for April has increased or decreased by more than £500 from March then the April figure will be highlighted red to indicate I need to take action.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There are different ways to do what you need, and we don't know which method will work better for you. If is it possible, more details, examples on the sheet that you have, and example on the result that you need. This will be more detailed to us in order to give you the best solution that you need.

Comment: I am monitoring sums in individuals bank accounts. Each month I need to identify if the account has risen or fallen by more than £500 when compared to the previous month. If for example John has 10000 in January and 11000 in February then I want the 11000 to show red as his capital has increased by more than 500. Alternatively if in February his capital was 10200 in February the 10200 would not be red. If his capital was 9500 in February it would show red.

Comment: Conditional Formatting is the best way to do what you want. Just make sure that you add the capital cell to be changed the format whenever the conditions are met. Hence, you need to use "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" from the Conditional Formatting rules. And you'll need to group sheets if you have multiple sheets with the same structure of bank statements to make the changes at once. If you give us a simple draft or screenshot on the sheets, we can do better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a condition on the field itself using conditional formatting in Excel.
This link might help you: [How to use Conditional Formatting to Highlight Data](https://www.timeatlas.com/excel-conditional-formatting/)

Here's an excerpt:

> To apply conditional formatting to one or more cells,
>
> Highlight your cell or range of cells.
>
> From the Format menu, select **Conditional Formatting…**
>
> In the Conditional formatting dialog, select **Cell Value Is** in the first drop-down box.
>
> Select a cell evaluator from the second drop down box. Your dialog may change and add another field.
>
> Enter your values in the remaining text boxes.
>
> Click the **Format…** button.
>
> Choose your format options from the **Font**, **Border** and **Patterns** tabs.
>
> Click **OK**.
>
> Click **OK** or add another condition.

Comment: Link answers are not acceptable on here. Please write out the general idea of what is on the site. You can leave the link as a reference but your answer should be solid if that site ever goes down or changes.

Comment: I have also added an excerpt from the link for you.

Comment: Perfect. Much better :) Thumbs up from me.

Comment: The value she wants to base the conditional formatting on is not in the cell to be formatted, so this exact solution won't work.

Comment: This is just a guide. I'm sure there'd be a way to tweak this to achieve the desired output. That's why I said 'this link might help you'.